# Get Data from GridView to RdotNet (R.net)

Tags: sql, asp.net, .net, r.net

my task is simple i just wanna take data from gridview to REngine do random function get back rows and show them back in the gridview, I tried that

```
            TextBox_Ville.Text = "I'm here";
            DataTable dtb = (DataTable)Session["Grid"];
            REngine engine = REngine.GetInstance();
            string[,] stringData = new string[dtb.Rows.Count, dtb.Columns.Count];
            for (int row = 0; row < dtb.Rows.Count; row++)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < dtb.Columns.Count; col++)
                {
                    stringData[row, col] = dtb.Rows[row].ItemArray[col].ToString();
                }
            }
            CharacterMatrix matrix = engine.CreateCharacterMatrix(stringData);
            engine.SetSymbol("myRDataFrame", matrix);
            engine.Evaluate("myRDataFrame <- as.data.frame(myRDataFrame, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)");
            //   engine.Evaluate("str(myRDataFrame)");
            DataFrame dataset = engine.Evaluate("myRDataFrame[sample(nrow(myRDataFrame), 1), ]").AsDataFrame();

            DataTable dtt = new DataTable();
            for (int i = 0; i < dataset.ColumnCount; ++i)
            {
                dtt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(dataset.ColumnNames[i]));
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < dataset.RowCount; ++i)
            {
                var row = dtt.NewRow();

                for (int k = 0; k < dataset.ColumnCount; ++k)
                {
                    row[dataset.ColumnNames[k]] = dataset[i, k];
                }

                dtt.Rows.Add(row);
            }

            GridView1.DataSource = dtt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
```

But it give me Stackoverflow error, can anyone help please. thanks :)

Comment: If you re-write this as a self contained example, it will be easier for the community to provide help.  I can't run your code as is and I don't know which line it is failing on.

Answer (score 0):

I see you omitted type when building your DataTable.  Perhaps that is the problem?

```
dtt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(dataset.ColumnNames[i], typeof(string)));
```

The other thing I noticed is that you use 'row' as an iterator in a for loop, then you use it again to build a DataRow.  I can't tell if it's a problem or not.